# ASP.NET MVC : get value from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email-attachments

I have create a WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC.

In this WebGrid I show two links:

```
webGrid.Column("", format: item => Html.ActionLink("PDF", "ExportPDF", new { id = item.sID }, new { target = "_blank" })),
webGrid.Column("", format: item => Html.ActionLink("E-mail", "SendEmail", new { id = item.sID }, new { target = "_blank" })),
```

The first link get the `item.sID` to controller for export file PDF

```
public void ExportPDF(int id)
{
    // code
}
```

The second link open a new `View` with form for send an email message

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Email", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.To, "To", htmlAttributes: new { @Class = "Mytextarea2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @Class = "Mytextarea2", placeholder = "To" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.To, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

I can't go retrieve and sending the value of `item.sID` a new `View` with form for send an email message

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

the question is

How to do get the value of item.sID from the View (with the form for sending the email message) to pass to ActionResult Email(PersonModel model) for export pdf with item.sID value?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Email(PersonModel model)
{
    string from = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"].ToString();
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, model.To))
    {
        mail.Subject = model.Subject;
        mail.Body = model.Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "xxxx";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Send(mail);
        ViewBag.Message = "Email";
        return View("Email", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? What value of id you are getting in SenEmail method?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the problem is how to get the id value from the e-mail view and get it to the controller for export and attachment the pdf file

Comment: What is the model type in view? Do you have Email action method in HoneController? Can you share code of it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i am stuck on Email action method in HomeController, pls see my question